# how i can configure SitesExplorer localhost in Oracle webcenter Sites IPv6?

Tags: oracle, explorer, sites, webcenter-sites

I installed Jump Start Kit Oracle webcenter sites and it works well but when i'm tryin to open SitesExplore to looks database don't works with the host name "localhost" but with 127.0.0.1 works well, but the links of webcenter works always with "localhost:port". Do you have any idea how i can solve it? Because i'm working with  host:"localhost"  in other pc and don't looks this problem.

Error: Unable to contact Oracle Webcenter sites on server "localhost" on port 9080

I understand that is the same "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" but I wonder because some machines works well with host "localhost" and other no.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem:

I delete ipv6 with this steps [link](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/kb/929852) and now i think that works well.

Answer (score 0):

I use machine name and that works well if localhost is not working.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: Oh sorry, what I meant was that I use Windows machine name in hostname field when trying to access SitesExplorer.exe rather than using localhost as sometimes it fails to run with localhost as hostname.